# Skippable Exception

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to skip all the exceptions during the batch run using the following config:

```
<chunk reader="aaaFileReader" writer="aaaDBWriter"
                commit-interval="100" skip-limit="100000">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                    <exclude
                        class="org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException" />
                </skippable-exception-classes>

            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="aaabatchFailureListener" />
            </listeners>
```

And I handle the exception in my listener. But when Spring Batch actually encounters an exception its not being skipped and the batch run ends with a failed state. The actual exception is a FlatFileParse Exception. How do I skip the FlatFileParseException?
Here is the log :

```
:18:21.257 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
15:18:21.257 [main] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:106) ~[spring-batch-core.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infr
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 5, input=[0254285458908060150983101150983         AK00055002035201401081044000804CK5861           00Twist,Oliver              AT&T                          20121208                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ]
    at org.springframework.batch.
```

Comment: [you can skip flatfile or NonSkippableReadException exception like this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659738/skip-flatfileparseexception-or-specific-exception-in-spring-batch/35755035#35755035)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the **FlatFileParseException** class on your batch job config, for example:

```
<batch:chunk reader="customImportReader" writer="customImporter" processor="customProcessor" commit-interval="1" skip-limit="10">
    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
</batch:chunk>
```

Comment: I found this helpful if not configuring with XML: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip

Answer (score 0):

> As per *Spring Batch Documentation* some of the exceptions are not qualified as skippable.

In your case its clear from logs that `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException` is not a skippable excepotion hence re throwing `org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException`.

---

Read more about [Configuring Skip Logic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html) section that says:

> For any exception encountered, the skippability will be determined by the nearest superclass in the class hierarchy. Any unclassifed exception will be treated as 'fatal'.

Read more about [NonSkippableReadException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/skip/NonSkippableReadException.html) that says:

> Fatal exception to be thrown when a read operation could not be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom fileReader and Override the doRead() method to always throw you CustomException.

   public class CustomFlatFileItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader {
   @Override
   protected T doRead() throws Exception {
       T itemRead=null;
       try {
           itemRead=   super.doRead();
       } catch (FlatFileParseException e) {
           throw new MyException(e.getMessage(), e);
       }
       return itemRead;}
   }
2. Override your job skip policy to always skip your custom exception as below:

   .skipPolicy((Throwable T, int skipCount) -> {
                   if (T instanceof BatchServiceException)
                       return true;
                   else
                       return false;