# skip FlatFileParseException or specific exception in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

Hi I have requirement to read (n number) of  flat file. During file reading  if received FileParseException: from reader then stop the current file reading and came out safely and process next file and continue  the job execution. currently i have this xml config but i don't want to go with this because i don't have a really skip limit count. is there any way to handle this scenario may be using ItemReaderListener ?

```
<chunk reader="flatFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter"
             commit-interval="10" skip-limit="2">
         <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
         </skippable-exception-classes>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip blank lines in CSV using FlatFileItemReader and chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673524/how-to-skip-blank-lines-in-csv-using-flatfileitemreader-and-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying a skip-limit, you can use a policy. There are several out-of-the-box skip policies, it sounds like you always want to skip (no limit), use AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy.

Example config :

```
<batch:skip-policy>   

     <bean:bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy"/>

</batch:skip-policy>
```

Comment: Thanks Doeleman for your valuable input.  your assumption is correct only i always want to skip some specific exception. could you please share some example.

Comment: Just add a skippable-exception-classes section inside your chunk element, like:                `<batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="MyException"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>`

Answer (score 0):

thanks Doeleman, based upon your input i am able to skip `exception using`AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy this is how i have implemented

```
public class SkipPolicy extends  AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy  {

    @Override
     public boolean shouldSkip(java.lang.Throwable t, int skipCount){

        if(t instanceof NonSkippableReadException){
            return true;
        }
        return false;

     }
}

xml config.

<batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader"  writer="mysqlItemWriter" 
                    commit-interval="2" skip-policy="mySkipPolicy">

<bean id="mySkipPolicy" class="com.model.SkipPolicy"/>
```